# Loop over a slice of structs and update value

Tags: pointers, go, struct, slice

I am getting data from source A and storing it in a slice of structs like so:

```
type ProductPrice struct {
    Type          string
    Sku           string
    UnitPrice     string
    PriceList     string
    standardPrice string
    specialPrice  string
    specialStart  string
    specialEnd    string
    pricingUnit   string
    categoryCode  string
    isOnSpecial   bool
}

func getProductPricesFromDatabase(instance string) []ProductPrice {
    rows, err := myDBConnection.Query(// My query here)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("There was an issue with the query for product price: ", err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    var productPrices []ProductPrice

    for rows.Next() {
        var product = ProductPrice{}
        err := rows.Scan(
            &product.Type,
            &product.Sku,
            &product.standardPrice,
            &product.specialPrice,
            &product.specialStart,
            &product.specialEnd,
            &product.pricingUnit,
            &product.PriceList,
            &product.categoryCode,
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("product price scan error: ", err)
        }

        productPrices = append(productPrices, product)
    }

    return productPrices
}
```

I am then getting some data from source B and storing it in a slice of structs like so:

```
type ContractProductPrice struct {
    CustID                 string
    PriceBy                string
    AppliesTo              string
    PriceList              string
    StartDate              string
    EndDate                string
    PricingAdjustmentType  string
    PricingAdjustmentValue string
    UseLowest              string
}

func getContractProductPricesFromDatabase(instance string) []ContractProductPrice {
    rows, err := myDBConnection.Query(// My query here)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("There was an issue with the query for contract product price: ", err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    var contractProductPrices []ContractProductPrice

    for rows.Next() {
        var product = ContractProductPrice{}
        err := rows.Scan(
            &product.CustID,
            &product.PriceBy,
            &product.AppliesTo,
            &product.PriceList,
            &product.StartDate,
            &product.EndDate,
            &product.PricingAdjustmentType,
            &product.PricingAdjustmentValue,
            &product.UseLowest,
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("contract product price scan error: ", err)
        }
        contractProductPrices = append(contractProductPrices, product)
    }

    return contractProductPrices
}
```

After getting the data from source B, I am wanting to update the slice of structs from source A with some data from source B.

```
productPrices := getProductPricesFromDatabase(instance)
contractProductPrices := getContractProductPricesFromDatabase(instance)

processedProductPrices := processProductPricesFromDatabase(productPrices, contractProductPrices)

func processProductPricesFromDatabase(productPrices []ProductPrice, contractProductPrices []ContractProductPrice) []ProductPrice {
    // Loop over contact prices and update relevant product prices
    for _, contractPrice := range contractProductPrices {
        for _, product := range productPrices {
            if contractPrice.AppliesTo == product.Sku {
                product.UnitPrice = contractPrice.PricingAdjustmentValue
            }
        }
    }

    return productPrices
}
```

However, after this runs, the unit prices in `processedProductPrices` is still empty.

From my searching, I understand what the issue is; Go passes by value and so I am not updating the original memory address and so the values are not changing.
However, I do not understand/know what I need to change to fix this given I am working with a slice of structs rather than a simpler example of a slice of number/strings etc.

How can I update `productPrices` so that when I return it, `processedProductPrices` is equal to the updated `productPrices` slice of structs?

Comment: You need to loop over `[]*ProductPrice`, i.e. pointers, to be able to modify them, else what you see inside the loop is a copy of each slice element as you already know. Or use indexing `productPrices[i].UnitPrice = ...`.

Comment: @mkopriva could you show me an example? I'm not sure how to refactor to what you suggest?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/vIumBqIVmh8 or https://play.golang.com/p/ST2qb0-JYC6

Comment: @mkopriva Your comments belong in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you're dealing with values that you know you'll need to modify, it is best, at least in my opinion, to use pointers. They'll make your life easier.

So instead of:

```
func getProductPricesFromDatabase(instance string) []ProductPrice {
    // ...
    var productPrices []ProductPrice

    for rows.Next() {
        var product = ProductPrice{}

        // ...
    }    
    return productPrices
}
```

I would recommend you refactor your code to:

```
func getProductPricesFromDatabase(instance string) []*ProductPrice {
    // ...
    var productPrices []*ProductPrice

    for rows.Next() {
        var product = new(ProductPrice)

        // ...
    }    
    return productPrices
}
```

Now do the same with `getContractProductPricesFromDatabase` and finally update the argument types to your `processProductPricesFromDatabase` function:

```
func processProductPricesFromDatabase(productPrices []*ProductPrice, contractProductPrices []*ContractProductPrice) []*ProductPrice {
    // Loop over contact prices and update relevant product prices
    for _, contractPrice := range contractProductPrices {
        for _, product := range productPrices {
            if contractPrice.AppliesTo == product.Sku {
                product.UnitPrice = contractPrice.PricingAdjustmentValue
            }
        }
    }
    return productPrices
}
```

---

As an alternative, if you want to keep using non-pointer types, you can directly modify the values referenced by the slice by indexing into it.

```
func processProductPricesFromDatabase(productPrices []ProductPrice, contractProductPrices []ContractProductPrice) []ProductPrice {
    // Loop over contact prices and update relevant product prices

    for _, contractPrice := range contractProductPrices {

        for i, _ := range productPrices {
            if contractPrice.AppliesTo == productPrices[i].Sku {
                productPrices[i].UnitPrice = contractPrice.PricingAdjustmentValue
            }
        }
    }

    return productPrices
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance! Works perfectly.